# How can I get the text value of TextView from a ViewController using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

```
class AlertViewController: UITableViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var alertText: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        alertText.text = "alert"
    }
}
```

So i want to get the text value in`AppDelegate.swift`, and I have this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let alertText = AlertViewController().alertText
    print(alertText.text)
    return true
}
```

I got this error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Comment: calling AlertViewController() won't call viewDidLoad. So yes, alerttext is nil, then you crash.
viewDidLoad is called only the first time the view is accessed (by you, or by UIKit)

Comment: thank you, i learn more about viewDialod function

Answer (score -1):

```
@IBOutlet weak var alertText: UITextView!
```

See how you instantiated this as a "weak" variable. That means it's not going to be instantiated unless it's needed. As Ro22e0 said, I'm not sure why you're calling this in the appDelegate but make sure that the class object is instantiated. Also the textField.text value is an optional so check for nil before you try to print it like so

```
if let alertText = AlertViewController.text {
    print(alertText)
}
```

Comment: That isn't what "weak" means

Comment: "Because a weak reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to, it is possible for that instance to be deallocated while the weak reference is still referring to it. Therefore, ARC automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that it refers to is deallocated." -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        print("text:", alertText.text)
}
```

AppDelegate start before the ViewController

Comment: In AppDelegate, i call AlertViewController(). viewDidAppear(true), and i still get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: viewDidAppear is called in ViewController not AppDelegate